# axioms of a Poisson process and Brownian motion

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Wikipedia says that since Brownian Motion $B$ on the real line satisfies

$$ \mathbf{E}(|B_t - B_s|^4) \le 2|s-t| ^2 $$

the Kolmogorov continuity theorem implies that there is a modification which is almost surely continuous.

Here is my question. If I start with the axiom of independent increments and the axiom that $B(s+t)-B(s)$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $t$, I think I can deduce from this formulas for all the finite distributions such as $\mathbf{P}(2<B_3<4,\, 5<B_4<6)$. From this I can construct the canonical Stochastic process which has this law, since I know the measures of cylinder sets, I have a measure on the Borel algebra of the topological space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology.

Here is where I run out of steam a bit. I want to down tools and say "Fine I have constructed a stochastic process which satisfies both axioms so I am done."  I can even ask if the set of discontinuous functions is measurable and has measure zero, as I am guessing it does.

If someone asked me  to apply Kolmogorov continuity, I would have to evaluate the left side of the equation above using only finite distributions and I do not know how to do that. Secondly, even if I succeeded in doing that, it would only tell me that there exists a modification which is almost surely continuous, but I believe that I already have that and I don't need to modify anything.

So it seems I already have an almost surely continuous Stochastic process that satisfies the two axioms so I have constructed Brownian motion with no effort, and  yet it seems I am expected to evaluate something else (the left side of the Kolmogorov continuity equation) in order to find a modification which I do not even need.  I am confused!

I have a similar question about Poisson processes, why don't people discard the axiom that sample paths are right continuous and just use the canonical Stocahstic process coming from the finite distributions. Saying it is possible to induce this from the subset of right continuous functions is like saying lengths of intervals in R are induced from their intersection with the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, why bother to do this? Again, confused.

I want to just delete the continuity axiom for Brownian Motion and the right continuity axiom for a Poisson Process and just use the canonical Stochastic process. These continuity conditions seem to be corollaries, saying that the canonical process based on the finite distributions satisfying the 2 Brownian motion axioms has that discontinuous functions have measure zero, and saying that the measure on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to the finite distributions of the Poisson process is determined by its restriction to right continuous functions. These are theorems though,   not axioms. What sense can it make to take a true theorem and insist it as an axiom??

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Minor point: the actual fourth moment of the increments of BM is $E(B_t - B_s)^4 = 3 |t-s|$

Comment: The issue is that information about regularity (continuity, right-continuity, etc.) of sample paths cannot be encoded as a measurable set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$. That is, the set $$C = \{\omega\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} : \omega\text{ is continuous} \}$$ does not belong to $\mathcal{B}$. In general, the space $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ cannot deal with information on properties of sample-paths. So, regularity of sample paths must be imposed by other means, and that is why it is often included as an axiom.